# What does x ^ 2 mean? in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

i'm sure it's very basic and I should understand it, but I don't!

I'm given this to do:

```
> a=int(input("Enter the value for the co-efficient of x^2. "))
> b=int(input("Enter the value for the co-efficient of x. "))
> c=int(input("Enter the value for the constant term. ")) s=b**2-4*a*c
> x1=(-b+(s**(1/2)))/2*a x2=(-b-(s**(1/2)))/2*a if a==0 and b==0:
>     print("The equation has no roots.") elif a==0:
>     print("The equation has only one root and it is", -c/b) elif s<0:
>     print("The roots are not real!") else:
>     print("The roots are", x1, "and", x2)
```

I get the right solution and everything right but I have no idea what the ^  is there for. The only reason I used it is because it was used in the other example during the lesson before the practice!

Comment: `x^2` means "x to the power of 2", i.e. "x squared". Please, please, please use google before asking questions.

Comment: @TomLord It doesn't mean x squared, x**2 means x squared

Comment: Yes, it does. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_(algebra) `x^2` is a very common mathematical notation for "x squared". But in some languages, the actual syntax for expressing a square is different - e.g. `x**2` or `pow(x, 2)`, etc.

Comment: FWIW, You _could_ use `x²` or `x\u00b2` in that string, assuming your terminal can handle Unicode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't 'mean' anything, not to Python; it is just another character in a string literal:

```
"Enter the value for the co-efficient of x^2. "
```

You could have written something else:

```
"Enter the value for the co-efficient of x to the power 2. "
```

and nothing but the output shown when asking for `input()` would have changed.

`^` is a common notation for exponents. In Python, `**` is used for exponents, and that is what the rest of the code uses.